# Discord.py bot sends messages from a different command when another command is input

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my code for a chatbot:

```py
if 'Hello' or 'hello' in message.content:
    await message.reply((random.choice(hello)))

if 'How are you' or 'how are you' in message.content:
    mention = ' Thanks for asking, ' + message.author.mention + '!'
    await message.channel.send((random.choice(howareyou)) + mention)
```

However, whenever I type 'hello' or 'how are you' into the chat separately, it sends both messages. How do I fix this?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, when you send 'hello' into the chat, it sends `random.choice(hello)`, and when you send 'how are you', it sends `random.choice(howareyou) + mention` because that's what you've asked the bot to do. If not, I think you want to check if the other string is there too in the message, using the `or` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of two reasons:

1. The [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) make the interpreter check the `in` operator before the `or` operator.
2. For strings, anything that is not an empty string is considered as having the value True if a boolean is asked. You can have more details in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) about what is considered `True` or `False`.

To your interpreter, your code looks like:

```py
if True or ('hello' in message.content):
    await message.reply((random.choice(hello)))

if True or ('how are you' in message.content):
    mention = ' Thanks for asking, ' + message.author.mention + '!'
    await message.channel.send((random.choice(howareyou)) + mention)
```

So:

1. `'hello' in message.content` and `'how are you' in message.content` becomes `True` of `False` depending on the situation
2. `'Hello' or True` becomes `True or True` which will become `True`. The same is true for `'Hello' or False`. The same is true for `'How are you'`
3. So your two `if` will always see that the condition is `True`and will always execute

To correct your situation simply:

```py
if 'Hello' in message.content or 'hello' in message.content:
    await message.reply((random.choice(hello)))

if 'How are you' in message.content or 'how are you' in message.content:
    mention = ' Thanks for asking, ' + message.author.mention + '!'
    await message.channel.send((random.choice(howareyou)) + mention)
```